# Firebase query and delete data in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase
[image]

I would like to delete the last deed within deeds which happens to be deed id: 1. I would like to do this without specifying anything other than deleting the last deed in deeds.

Here is what I have tried already, but I receive no function errors because i'm returning query type objects.

```
const deedRef = admin.database().ref('/deeds');
deedRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.val().remove();
})
```

And

```
const deedRef = admin.database().ref('/deeds');
deedRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((deedSnapshot) =>{
         deedSnapshot.remove();
    })
})
```

And I've tried this

```
const deedRef = admin.database().ref('/deeds');
deedRef.limitToLast(1).remove();
```

How can I reference the last deed in deeds and remove it? The last deed will constantly change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were getting close:

```
const deedRef = admin.database().ref('/deeds');
deedRef.limitToLast(1).once("value", (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((deedSnapshot) =>{
         deedSnapshot.ref.remove();
    })
})
```

Comment: It's easiest to remember that you need a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) to do any write operations. A [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) is not a `Reference`, but you can get is reference by calling `ref` on it.

Comment: Frank would you be charged for an operation like this? (i.e. would it count as "downloaded" data as you've queried for it, even if you haven't accessed any data inside that node?)

Comment: A `DataSnapshot` contains a snapshot of the data. That means the data is available in the client, so it has been downloaded, and you will be charged for the bandwidth.